# What data collection can be used for rows["column"][rowIndex] in Java?

Tags: c#, java, collections

I'm trying to find a similar or equivalent data collection used in C# DataRow class, which lets me choose the column name and row index.

Is there anything similar to this that can be used in Java?

Comment: If you retrieve and want to hold DB rows to iterate through them, wouldn't java.sql.ResultSet do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to Etienne de Martel's answer, but I would strongly recommend using a Map of sorts. A HashMap is almost certainly he best way.

I would first make a 2D array of values, for distinguishing purposes, I'll call them Doubles:

```
Double[][] values = new Double[colNum][rowNum];
```

I would then for each column name map an integer to it:

```
Map <String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.add("Column_0_Name",0);
map.add("Column_1_Name",1);
map.add("Column_2_Name",2);
map.add("Column_3_Name",3);
//...
map.add("Column_(colNum-1)_Name",colNum-1);
```

Then using these two together, I would create a function.

```
public double getValue(String columnName, int row){
 int colNum = map.get(columnName);
 return values[colNum][row];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that implements `Map<String, List<Integer>>` would probably do what you need, such as:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> data = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
// ...
data.put("column", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

But perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Just one note - you cannot use primitives in Java collections as they're not Objects (and they are not nullable), List<Integer> would be correct instead. I don't know much about C#, but I believe the situation is a bit different there, 'int' is somewhat an alias for an Int(eger), which is object.

Comment: @Arturs Ooops, too much C#! Thanks! And indeed, int in C# is an alias for System.Int32, which is a struct (or rather, a "value type").